# Change the border color of the bootstrap popover arrow?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to work out how to change (or add) a border color for the default Bootstrap popover arrow? I'm using the bottom arrow if it matters.

I have read some other questions and some suggested something like this:

```
.popover.bottom > .arrow:after {
     border-bottom-color: yourColorHere; 
 }
```

However this fills in the color of the whole visible part of the arrow, what I want is just colors on the borders of the arrow.

Can this be done?

Btw....... If possible, I would like a solution without having to recompile the css.

Comment: I forked a gist to customise color of border, background and text:
 https://gist.github.com/dsnoeck/9ce65ec8d025796c3be53e7c06880eab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just remove the `:after` selector to get the behavior you need

```
.popover.bottom > .arrow {
  border-bottom-color: yourColorHere; 
}
```